# Why I can't use virtual register variables in instruction composition?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, instructions

I am trying to utilize instruction composition to make my LLVM IR code more readable, by performing multiple operations at once. I have four virtual register variables that I want to add together and store the result into one `%sum` variable.

Here's my code:

```
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu"

define i32 @main() {
    %obj1 = insertvalue {i32, i32} {i32 2, i32 3}, i32 2, 0
    %obj2 = insertvalue {i32, i32} %obj1, i32 7, 1

    %1 = extractvalue {i32, i32} %obj1, 0
    %2 = extractvalue {i32, i32} %obj1, 1
    %3 = extractvalue {i32, i32} %obj2, 0
    %4 = extractvalue {i32, i32} %obj2, 1

    %sum = add i32
        add (i32 %1, i32 %2),
        add (i32 %3, i32 %4)

    ret i32 %sum
}
```

This code with the instruction composition, to add multiple virtual register variables together, looks syntactically correct to me. However the compiler (or the assembler) displays an error:

```
 $ llvm-as insertvalue_test.ll -o insertvalue_test.bc
llvm-as: insertvalue_test.ll:14:18: error: invalid use of function-local name
        add (i32 %1, i32 %2),
                 ^
```

I do not know what that error means. Even if I replace the virtual register variables with constants, the code compiles and runs fine:

```
    %sum = add i32
        add (i32 1, i32 2),
        add (i32 3, i32 4)
```

Also when I try to just add these two register variables together using one `add` instruction, it works fine.

```
%sum = add i32 %1, %2
```

However the problem occurs when I attempt to use multiple `add` instructions in instruction combination to add multiple register variables together.

Answer (score 2):

Well. Because this is not a valid LLVM IR :) The code in

```
    %sum = add i32
        add (i32 1, i32 2),
        add (i32 3, i32 4)
```

represents so-called constant expression (https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#constant-expressions) and therefore is valid.

The arguments to instructions must be SSA values, so you need to name them (or use the positional naming).

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the key point is that LLVM won't invent a name for the internal temporary when it's a runtime temporary.  But the sum of 2 constants can become a single compile-time value that doesn't need a name.

Comment: Names are required for all SSA values. Constant values are unique (this is same value, you cannot create a second instance of a constants), so they are nameless. The key point here is that there are no "internal" nor "runtime" temporaries as well as "compile-time values".